# How can I open new Chrome window with different arguments?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I want to have a new Chrome window with same origin policy (CORS) disabled for development, while keeping the existing one open for browsing. I already have tried the [CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) plugin but it does not work for local files.

Apparently, this can be [done on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/19317888?noredirect=1#comment40557244_19317888). Can it be done on OSX (10.8) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
nohup /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security 2>&1 &
```

nohup lets you quit Terminal without killing the process.
Arguments are added as normal before the `2>…` redirection.

Alternatively, you can try:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Opened a new window but CORS was still enabled (argument was not in effect)...

Comment: @user Edited answer—try that?

Comment: No luck, just makes the last viewed chrome window focused...

Comment: any updates guys?